# Измение структуры таблицы БД

Tags: sql, excel, таблицы

В настоящее время идет таблица со следующей структурой - дата, время1, время2, время3 и т д
То есть запись имеет вид - 22.06.2015 значение1, значение2, значение3 и т д. Хочу сделать чтобы в каждой строке для каждой даты было только одно значение.
То есть
22.06.2015 значение1
22.06.2015 значение2
22.06.2015 значение3
...
Как изменить структуру с минимальными усилиями? Сейчас 60 строк и 25 столбцов. По итогу хочу переформатировать в два столбца - дата значение

Comment: Так это в таблице Excel или в таблице на сервере БД?

Answer (score 0):

Все просто.

```
CREATE TABLE table2(date date_, int v);
INSERT INTO table2(date_, v) select (date_, v1) from Test;
INSERT INTO table2(date_, v) select (date_, v2) from Test;
INSERT INTO table2(date_, v) select (date_, v3) from Test;
INSERT INTO table2(date_, v) select (date_, v4) from Test;
...
```